# How to have Google Spreadsheets automatically complete cells with previously used data

Tags: google-sheets, automation

I'm using a Google Spreadsheet to fill in my mileage. Since I'm using many addresses more than once, I want to make the process of filling in easier by (like Excel or Open Office) having the spreadsheet automatically complete my previously-used data.

An example:

```
 9-5-2013 | home (1033DJ 2)       | customer A (1084BA 6) | 20km | 0 | meeting | Somewhere  
 9-5-2013 | customer A (1084BA 6) | home (1033DJ 2)       | 20km | 0 | meeting | Somewhere                  
10-5-2013 | home (1033DJ 2)       | customer B (1000AA 1) | 70km | 0 | meeting | Somewhere  
10-5-2013 | customer B (1000AA 1) | home (1033DJ 2)       | 70km | 0 | meeting | Somewhere
```

Now when I'm writing "home" I'd like to have the spreadsheet autocomplete or suggest "home (1033DJ 2)".

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to `Enable autocomplete` under the `Tools` menu.

[image: Tools menu]

Comment: haha! that was too easy, @nicholas!   
my solution was to make an extra row 'H', in which cell 'H1' had a formula '=B1', and have the content of row 'B' validated based by the content of row 'H'. This way it worked as well, but way more complicated as checking 'enable autocomplete'...